# How do you display elements of the linked list, without going into a non terminating while loop?

Tags: c, data-structures, linked-list, traversal, non-termination

I,m writing  a C code for implementing and traversing a Linked list with a while loop.
I'm unable to figure out what I wrote wrong in code. The code instead of terminating in while (a!=NULL) and displaying all the elements in the linked list,it goes into an infinite loop. here is the code.....

```
    #include<stdio.h>
    #include<stdlib.h>
    struct node{
        int data;
        struct node * next;
     };
     
     void Display(struct node * a){
         printf("The elements are :");
         while(a!=NULL){
             printf("%d\n",a->data);
             a=a->next;
         }
    
     }
     int main(){
         int choice;
         struct node * head, * new_node,  * temp;
         head = NULL;  // head points to NULL
                            
         new_node=(struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
         while(choice){
             
             printf("Enter the Data");
             scanf("%d", &new_node->data); // Entering value in new_node
             new_node->next=NULL;
             if (head == NULL)
             {
    
                 head = temp = new_node;
    
             }
             else
             {
                 temp->next = new_node;
                 temp = new_node; 
             }
             printf("Enter 0 for ending and 1 for continuing");
             scanf("%d", &choice);
         }
         Display(head);
         return 0;
     }
```

Output:
enter the data1
enter 0 for ending and 1 for continuing 1
enter the data 2
enter 0 for ending and 1 for continuing 1
enter the data 3
enter 0 for ending and 1 for continuing 0
3

3

3

3

3

3

3

...... not terminating

Comment: I am seeing only one node allocation. How is it supposed to work for more?

Comment: like how? I'm new to this, so please be a bit more specific

Comment: Specifically, your program executes `malloc` one single time. While it needs to execute it for each `node` you want to create.

Comment: thank you so much, I got what I did wrong

Comment: Note that `choice` is not initialized when you first execute `while(choice){` and the value might easily be zero, in which case the loop won't be entered.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<stdio.h>
    #include<stdlib.h>
    struct node{
        int data;
        struct node * next;
     };
     
     void Display(struct node * a){
         printf("The elements are :");
         while(a!=NULL){
             printf("%d\n",a->data);
             a=a->next;
         }
    
     }
     int main(){
         int choice;
         struct node * head, * temp;
         head = NULL;  // head points to NULL
                            
         
         while(choice){
             struct node *new_node=(struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
             printf("Enter the Data");
             scanf("%d", &new_node->data); // Entering value in new_node
             new_node->next=NULL;
             if (head == NULL)
             {
    
                 head = temp = new_node;
    
             }
             else
             {
                 temp->next = new_node;
                 temp = new_node; 
             }
             printf("Enter 0 for ending and 1 for continuing");
             scanf("%d", &choice);
         }
         Display(head);
         return 0;
     }
```

According to [Eugene Sh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4253229/eugene-sh), this code will work